# error:Constructor in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, string

Writing a code that takes a string being a phone number with letters in the place of numbers and then decodes that string into just numbers. When I'm writing my tester class it's telling me that the constructor from my other class cannot be applied to the given types in my test cases.

This is the main chunk of the code.

```
public class PhoneNumber
{
    String phoneNumber;
    String telNumber;
    public PhoneNumber(String num, String telNum)
    {
        phoneNumber = num;
        telNumber = telNum;
    }

    public String decodePhoneNumber()
    {
        //Takes string form phone number and decodes based on number pad
        //Find code that makes if statement not care about caps
        //so if a || b || c number[cnt] = 1 etc..
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < phoneNumber.length(); cnt++)
        {
            char num = phoneNumber.toLowerCase().charAt(cnt);
            if ((num == 'a') || (num == 'b') || (num == 'c'))
            {
                //number is 2
                telNumber = telNumber + "2";
            }
            else if ((num == 'd') || (num == 'e') || (num == 'f'))
            {
                //number is 3
                telNumber = telNumber +"3";
            }
            else if ((num == 'g') || (num == 'h') || (num == 'i'))
            {
                //number is 4
                telNumber = telNumber +"4";
            }
            else if ((num == 'j') || (num == 'k') || (num == 'l'))
            {
                //number is 5
                telNumber = telNumber +"5";
            }
            else if ((num == 'm') || (num == 'n') || (num == 'o'))
            {
                //number is 6
                telNumber = telNumber +"6";
            }
            else if ((num == 'p') || (num == 'q') || (num == 'r') || (num == 's'))
            {
                //number is 7
                telNumber = telNumber +"7";
            }
            else if ((num == 't') || (num == 'u') || (num == 'v'))
            {
                //number is 8
                telNumber = telNumber +"8";
            }
            else
            {
                //number is 9
                telNumber = telNumber +"9";
            }
        }
        return telNumber;
    }
}
```

This is my test class:

```
public class TestPhoneNumber
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        PhoneNumber ph1 = new PhoneNumber("1-800-ILOVENY");
        System.out.println("Decoded phone number: " +ph1.decodedPhoneNumber());
    }
}
```

The error is coming from line 5 in the test class.

Comment: Your `PhoneNumber`'s only constructor takes two string parameters.

Comment: Wow, simple oversight on my part. Been looking at a few different projects today so its been a long day. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

`PhoneNumber` class constructor has two string arguments `public PhoneNumber(String num, String telNum)` pass another string arguments or create another constructor with one String arguments.

Intialize the object like this

```
PhoneNumber ph1 = new PhoneNumber("XXXXX","1-800-ILOVENY");
```

or create another constructor of one String arguments in the `PhoneNumber` class

```
public PhoneNumber( String telNum)
    {

        telNumber = telNum;
    }
```